# How to upload Image in Database in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, database, laravel, image, laravel-5

I'm making an app in Laravel 5.7 . I want to upload image in database through it and I want to show it from database.

I have tried different methods around the Internet as I was getting issues in

```
Intervention\Image\Facades\Image
```

I followed many advices from Internet make changes in  **config.app** 
made changes in **Composer**

At the end used

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as Image;
```

So I get resolved from issue "Undefined class Image"
but now I' m getting issues as "Undefined class File",
Method getClientOriginalExtension not found.
Method  Upsize, make not found.

My code is

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use File;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as Image;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class UserController extends Controller

{
//

protected $user;

/**
 * [__construct description]
 * @param Photo $photo [description]
 */
public function __construct(
    User $user )
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Display photo input and recent images
 * @return view [description]
 */
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('profile', compact('users'));
}

public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required',
        'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    //check if image exist
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $images = $request->file('image');

        //setting flag for condition
        $org_img = $thm_img = true;

        // create new directory for uploading image if doesn't exist
        if( ! File::exists('images/originals/')) {
            $org_img = File::makeDirectory('images/originals/', 0777, true);
        }
        if ( ! File::exists('images/thumbnails/')) {
            $thm_img = File::makeDirectory('images/thumbnails', 0777, true);
        }

        // loop through each image to save and upload
        foreach($images as $key => $image) {
            //create new instance of Photo class
            $newPhoto = new $this->user;
            //get file name of image  and concatenate with 4 random integer for unique
            $filename = rand(1111,9999).time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //path of image for upload
            $org_path = 'images/originals/' . $filename;
            $thm_path = 'images/thumbnails/' . $filename;

            $newPhoto->image     = 'images/originals/'.$filename;
            $newPhoto->thumbnail = 'images/thumbnails/'.$filename;

            //don't upload file when unable to save name to database
            if ( ! $newPhoto->save()) {
                return false;
            }

            // upload image to server
            if (($org_img && $thm_img) == true) {
                Image::make($image)->fit(900, 500, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->upsize();
                })->save($org_path);
                Image::make($image)->fit(270, 160, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->upsize();
                })->save($thm_path);
            }
        }
    }

    return redirect()->action('UserController@index');

}

}
```

Please suggest me any Image Upload code without updating repositories or suggest me how can I remove issues from this code.

Comment: *I want to upload image in database* - means you want to store `blob` in the database, or you want to store `path/to/your/image.jpg` in the database?

Comment: Image to the database ...

Comment: You didn't understand me. You can store path to image file or store image as binary object

Answer (score 1):

The beginning of time read below link because laravel handled create directory and hash image and put directory 
[laravel file system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads) 
then read file name when stored on directory and holds name on table field when need image retrieve name field and call physical address on server

Answer (score 0):

```
$upload_id = $request->file('FILENAME');
$file_name = time().$upload_id->getClientOriginalName();
$destination = 
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/adminbusinessplus/storage/uploads';
$request->file('FILENAME')->move($destination, $file_name);


$string="123456stringsawexs";
$extension = pathinfo($upload_id, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$path = $destination.'/'.$file_name;
$public =1;
$user_id = $request->logedin_user_id;
$hash = str_shuffle($string);

$request->user_id = $request->logedin_user_id;
$request->name = $file_name;
$request->extension = $extension;
$request->path = $path;
$request->public = $public;
$request->hash = $hash;

//$request INSERT INTO MODEL uploads
$file_id = Module::insert("uploads", $request);
```